# Retrieving viewport height of screen in mobile browsers with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to get the viewport height in mobile browsers WITHOUT the height of the browser bar but all of the solutions I've attempted have come up short.

What others have suggested is using the below, however it does not work for me. I still get a blank white bar at the bottom of the window when scrolling

```
var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
$('.mobile-nav-wrapper').height(screenHeight)
```

Comment: `window.innerHeight` will not consider scroll height...

Comment: There shouldn't be a scroll at all, assuming innerHeight is giving me the correct viewport height minus the browser bar. Thats my issue.

Comment: Have you set `*{padding:0;margin:0;}` ?

Comment: Yeah, the issue only exists within mobile browsers. Displays correctly  and desktop and chromes mobile inspection tool.

Comment: I am curious to execute your code via snippet or Fiddle...

Comment: Which mobile device are you testing this on? There are a ton of issues with the way height is calculated especially in Safari Mobile.
Specifically - it usually has to do with some kind of taskbar or action sheet that's not being considered.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

I don't have an answer using jQuery. But using a plain/vanilla JavaScript wouldn't cause any issue :).
Following script allows you to detect the Viewport size (height and width) reliably.

https://github.com/tysonmatanich/viewportSize

Sample usage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = viewportSize.getWidth();
    var height = viewportSize.getHeight();
</script>
```

I have used it in couple of projects, were i have to re-initialize some widgets based on current Viewport width/height rather than using window width/height (Window width/height calculation isn't consistent in all browsers - some include scroll bar size 16px as a part of window width and some doesn't).

Sample Test page:
http://tysonmatanich.github.io/viewportSize/

**Solution 2: (Just for reference - Not an answer to OP's question, though it is related so I thought that it can remain)**

Well modernizr has a very good addition Modernizr.Mq. Through which you can cross check which break point range you are in...

```
if(Modernizr.mq("(min-width:320px)")){
//Do job 1
}
else if (Modernizr.mq("(min-width:768px)")){
//Do job 2
}
```

or 
based on height

Modernizr.mq("(min-height: 800px)")

http://tysonmatanich.github.io/viewportSize/

Comment: That is what OP would have wanted in this case :). Any way I was typing a detailed answers

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is scrollHeight

> The scrollHeight property returns the entire height of an element in
>   pixels, including padding, but not the border, scrollbar or margin.

You can try this:

```
document.body.scrollHeight
```